# jinja2 get list of attributes

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I'm using salt + jinja2 to template a context.xml file. I have the following pillar:

```
context:
  db_server: some_server
  resources:
    some_customer:
      name: some_name
      user: some_user
      passwd: some_passwd
    this_customer:
      name: this_name
      user: this_user
      passwd: this_passwd
```

I need to create a string with a list of the names for each customer. Right now I have this:

```
{%- set nameList = pillar['context']['resources']|list()|join(', ') %}
```

This gives me this list: `'some_customer, this_customer'`. I'd like this list: `'some_name, this_name'`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following one-liner worked for me:

```
{%- set nameList = pillar['context']['resources'].values()
                 |map(attribute='name')|join(', ') %}
```