# How to fix "Undefind error" while parsing a dictionary in ansible registered variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm creating some ec2 instances from a specific image, then trying to get a list of disks attached to these instances.

The problem is when I try to loop over the registered variable from the create instance task, I got an error

I have tried the solution from this post but with no luck

[ansible get aws ebs volume id which already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659564/ansible-get-aws-ebs-volume-id-which-already-exist)

```
- name: create instance
  ec2:
    region: us-east-1
    key_name: xxxxxxx
    group: xxxxxx
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    image: "{{ instance_ami }}"
    wait: yes
    wait_timeout: 500
    instance_tags:
      Name: "{{ item.name  }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.subnet }}"
  register: ec2
  loop: "{{ nodes }}"

- name: show attached volumes Ids
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.block_device_mapping | map(attribute='volume_id')   }}"
  loop: "{{ ec2.results[0].instances }}"
```

while printing only `msg: "{{ item.block_device_mapping }}"` I get:

```
    "msg": {
        "/dev/sda1": {
            "delete_on_termination": true,
            "status": "attached",
            "volume_id": "vol-xxxxxxx"
        },
        "/dev/xvdb": {
            "delete_on_termination": false,
            "status": "attached",
            "volume_id": "vol-xxxxxx"
        },
        "/dev/xvdc": {
            "delete_on_termination": false,
            "status": "attached",
            "volume_id": "vol-xxxxxx"
        }
    }
```

but when I use 
 `msg: "{{ item.block_device_mapping | map(attribute='volume_id') }}"`
I get this error:

```
"msg": "[AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined]"
```

Comment: It's logical, since item.block_device_mapping has 1 attribute with a name like /dev/sda1
From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387845/jinja2-get-list-of-attributes you can see how to make a list of all attribute names, which you can then loop through.

Comment: @HermanTheGermanHesse, thanks a lot for your comment and the link. 
working perfect now. 
```
msg: "{{  item.block_device_mapping.values() | map(attribute='volume_id')  | list  }}"
````

Comment: Would you mind if I post it as an answer?

Comment: No. please do :)

Answer (score 1):

The task below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}: {{ block_device_mapping[item].volume_id }}"
  loop: "{{ block_device_mapping.keys() }}"
```

gives the *{device: volume_id}* tuples (grep msg):

```
"msg": "/dev/xvdb: vol-xxxxxx"
"msg": "/dev/xvdc: vol-xxxxxx"
"msg": "/dev/sda1: vol-xxxxxxx"
```

To iterate instances use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). The task below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.block_device_mapping|json_query('*.volume_id') }}"
  loop: "{{ ec2.results[0].instances }}"
```

gives:

```
"msg": [
    "vol-xxxxxx", 
    "vol-xxxxxx", 
    "vol-xxxxxxx"
]
```

and the task below with [zip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters)

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.block_device_mapping.keys()|zip(
             item.block_device_mapping|json_query('*.volume_id'))|list }}"
  loop: "{{ ec2.results[0].instances }}"
```

gives the list of lists:

```
"msg": [
    [
        "/dev/xvdb", 
        "vol-xxxxxx"
    ], 
    [
        "/dev/xvdc", 
        "vol-xxxxxx"
    ], 
    [
        "/dev/sda1", 
        "vol-xxxxxxx"
    ]
]
```

and the task below with [dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter)

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ dict (item.block_device_mapping.keys()|zip(
                   item.block_device_mapping|json_query('*.volume_id'))) }}"
  loop: "{{ ec2.results[0].instances }}"
```

gives the tuples

```
"msg": {
    "/dev/sda1": "vol-xxxxxxx", 
    "/dev/xvdb": "vol-xxxxxx", 
    "/dev/xvdc": "vol-xxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The mistake:**

So the main mistake you made was thinking of `item.block_device_mapping` as if it was the map you wanted to work with instead of a map within a map. That is, the keys that you have to first find would, according to the `msg` that you printed `/dev/sda`, `/dev/xvdb` and `/dev/xvdc`.

So first you'd have to make an array with the keys of the parent map. [In the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387845/jinja2-get-list-of-attributes) you can see the necessary code to make Jinja get you the necessary strings:

```
# The necessary filter to get that array should be something along these lines
item['block_device_mapping'] | list() | join(', ')
```

You should register that to then loop over,giving you the keys you need to access those elements' attributes.